# Periodic solution of ODE, why does my counterexample not work?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am considering the ordinary differential equation of form $\frac{dN}{dt}= f(N)$, for example $\frac{dN}{dt} = N$. I know that this kind of ode has no non-constant periodic solution.

However, I am thinking about $N(t)=\sin(t)$. Since I can write
$$ \frac{dN}{dt} = \cos(t) = \sqrt{1-N^2} :=f(N).$$

So the above differential equation does have periodic solution.

I don't understand why my example is not a good counterexample. My feeling is that my example has restriction on N ($-1\leq N\leq1$). Am I correct?

Comment: Literally, the circular functions are not global solutions to that ODE: $\sqrt{1 - N^2}$ is non-negative by definition, while $\cos$ and $\sin$ aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand the comment: Because $f(N) = \sqrt{1 - N^{2}}$ is non-negative, every solution of $N' = f(N)$ is non-decreasing. The solutions of this equation are not the circular functions "globally," but only on some interval of length $\pi$.

For example, $N(t) = \sin t$ is a solution of $N' = f(N)$ on $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$, or on any interval where $\sin$ is non-decreasing. Similarly, for each real $t_{0}$ the function $N(t) = \sin(t - t_{0})$ is a solution of $[t_{0} - \frac{\pi}{2}, t_{0} + \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Generally, for each real $t_{0}$, there is a solution
$$
N(t) = \begin{cases}
  -1 & t \leq t_{0} - \tfrac{\pi}{2}, \\
  \sin(t - t_{0}) & t_{0} - \tfrac{\pi}{2} \leq t \leq t_{0} + \tfrac{\pi}{2}, \\
  1 & t < t_{0} + \tfrac{\pi}{2}.
\end{cases}
$$
Conversely, every non-constant solution is of this type. (Note separately that this ODE does not have unique solutions for give initial values: The function $f$ is not Lipschitz at $\pm1$.)

[image: Solutions of a trig-like ODE]